# Android app not running on emulator nor real device

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I've installed eclipse **(JUNO version), SDK, ADT (20.0.3)** and configured them through the Developer.android.com. After that I made a virtual device on eclipse **(Android 4.1 API level 16)** as well, but when I run the **"Hello World"** application in eclipse, the emulator is running with out error but the app is not running on the emulator.
There is also the problem with real device. I use Windows 7/64 bit and HTC incredible S phone. When I connect the device to my pc, windows detect it, but eclipse does not detect it. (The USB Debugging is enable on device and USB driver is updated on windows).
I tried different solutions like reinstalling eclpise, SDK and ADT, removing ADV and creating the new one,... but the problem did not solve.

Comment: Can you post a little more information about your project?  Did you actually create an Android project?  Is your emulator showing up in the eclipse devices?

Comment: sometimes the emulator is not really connected with the eclipse , and as you mentioned you developed it for 4.1, your device is not at jellybeans i guess, make a little more effort to make things work, try rebooting and using ddbms and selecting the device

Comment: Yes, I created an Android project through the instructions on developer.android and the emulator I created is shown on AVD manager list as a valid one.

Answer (score 2):

Did u located your android sdk? If not,locate the sdk as follows:

```
open Eclipse->Windows->preferences->Android->Select your android sdk folder.
```

then please try to run you program. Tell me the status after that.

Comment: I located my android sdk but I had this problem. This is what I can see on console after running the program:
[2012-09-27 14:00:58 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2012-09-27 14:00:58 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-27 14:00:58 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-09-27 14:00:58 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'android'
[2012-09-27 14:00:58 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'android'