# Android sdk locating

Tags: android

I am beginner in android.I faced some problems durinng sdk locating.How to **locate android sdk**?Please help me.
*Thanks*

Comment: I don't under stand your question, make it more clear. but if you mean the install location, under my windows pc it's under: C:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk-windows

Comment: you need to install plugins Help->Install New software-> Add.. Name: Android Location  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locate the sdk as follows:

```
open Eclipse->Windows->preferences->Android->Select your android sdk folder.
```

you can refer to this link also [Android app not running on emulator nor real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613250/)

Comment: thanks for prompt reply and it helps me

Comment: if you got the solution, mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

If you're using .zip then extract it to your favorite location

If you're using .exe then choose your favorite location to install to

If Eclipse can't locate your Android SDK folder, consider install ADT and connect SDK with Eclipse, see [instruction here](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/install-android-sdk-eclipse-and-emulator-avds/)